# Creating an expensive object in Python unittest to be shared across all tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm trying to write the tests for my database application. Right now this is my structure:

```
application_files
test/
    __init__.py
    test1.py
    test2.py
```

I want to create a temporary database once, and I want that database to be used by all tests. In `__init__.py` I have the following:

```
__init__.py:

class ApplicationTestCase(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        create_database()

    def setUp(self):
        clear_database()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(self):
        kill_database()
```

And in test1.py:

```
from . import ApplicationTestCase

class TestObject1(ApplicationTestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def do_test_a(self):
        whatever()

    def do_test_b(self):
        whatever()
```

test2.py is almost identical to test1.py

Currently, my temporary database is created then deleted for both test1 and test2. And I only want it to be created then deleted once. I've tried adding `def setUpModule():` in `__init__.py` but the function doesn't seem to be touched at all.

Comment: i've used setUpModule / tearDownModule in each test file with success, maybe try that, at least it should reduce the number of times your db is created/dropeed.

Comment: You mean adding setUpModule/tearDownModule in test1.py and test2.py? I just tried this and it's still creating the database twice. But if it did work, I feel like it defeats the purpose of using a testing framework. I shouldn't have identical setUpModule/tearDownModule calls in each test file.

Comment: any chance of putting all of your tests that depend on the database into one file, or do you see your db-specific tests ballooning?

Comment: You're going to have to manually create a test suite from those two tests and manually create a test runner to setup and tear down the DB. Make sure your tests work on disjoint data sets in the DB.

Comment: @Dan Do you have an example I could see?